# Android send image from javamail api

Tags: android, image, file, email, jakarta-mail

i am stuck in a project trying to send an image in the body of the mail that i am sending in my app, someone knows how can i do that?

here is the part of the code that i send the mail:

```
try {
                    String[] recipients = {editText.getText().toString()};
                    SendEmailAsyncTask email = new SendEmailAsyncTask();
                    email.m = new Mail(Base64Decoder.decoderBase64(ajudaquimail), Base64Decoder.decoderBase64(ajudaquipass));
                    email.m.set_from("ajudaquisuporte@gmail.com");
                    email.m.setBody("Seu amigo " + userName + " Te convida para participar do Aplicativo Ajudaqui, verifique também o grupo " + groupName + " para que possam compartilhar de suas ajudas: \n\n LINK PARA O APP:\n " + link);
                    email.m.get_multipart();
                    email.m.set_to(recipients);
                    email.m.set_subject("AJUDAQUI - CONVITE");
                    email.execute();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensagem enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha ao enviar mensagem, Verifique o email digitado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

here is my Mail object:

```
package studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaquioficial.helper;

/**
 * Created by bruno on 31/07/2017.
 */

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by brandonjenniges on 11/6/15.
 */
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;


    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;
    private View _view;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body
        _view = null;
        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            InputStream is = null;
```

// HERE I AM TRYING TO GET MY IMAGE FROM ASSETS AND PUTTING IN THE DATA SOURCE
//BUT IS WRONG AND HERE IS MY DOUBT

```
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource("invite.jpg");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName("invite.jpg");
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            msg.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }


    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public String get_user() {
        return _user;
    }

    public void set_user(String _user) {
        this._user = _user;
    }

    public String get_pass() {
        return _pass;
    }

    public void set_pass(String _pass) {
        this._pass = _pass;
    }

    public String[] get_to() {
        return _to;
    }

    public void set_to(String[] _to) {
        this._to = _to;
    }

    public String get_from() {
        return _from;
    }

    public void set_from(String _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }

    public String get_port() {
        return _port;
    }

    public void set_port(String _port) {
        this._port = _port;
    }

    public String get_sport() {
        return _sport;
    }

    public void set_sport(String _sport) {
        this._sport = _sport;
    }

    public String get_host() {
        return _host;
    }

    public void set_host(String _host) {
        this._host = _host;
    }

    public String get_subject() {
        return _subject;
    }

    public void set_subject(String _subject) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }

    public boolean is_auth() {
        return _auth;
    }

    public void set_auth(boolean _auth) {
        this._auth = _auth;
    }

    public boolean is_debuggable() {
        return _debuggable;
    }

    public void set_debuggable(boolean _debuggable) {
        this._debuggable = _debuggable;
    }

    public Multipart get_multipart() {
        return _multipart;
    }

    public void set_multipart(Multipart _multipart) {
        this._multipart = _multipart;
    }

    public View get_view() {
        return _view;
    }

    public void set_view(View _view) {
        this._view = _view;
    }
}
```

if someone knows how to solve that, it will be very grateful
tks

Answer (score -1):

First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then update your original post with the new code.

You have an addAttachment method, but you're never calling it.  Did you copy this code from someone else without understanding how it works?

The code you have is using the same MimeBodyPart (messageBodyPart) for both the main text and the image attachment; you need one for each.

And if you really want the image to be "in the body" of the message, you need to create a multipart/related message with a text/html main body part and a related image/jpeg part containing the image that's referenced from the html part using cid: URL references.